# Something is wrong with the iPhone 6 Plus tableView.separatorInset

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, iphone-6-plus

Something is up with our table view cell separators on the iPhone 6 Plus. I created a blank test project with a custom cell with only one label and a 15pt constraint to the leading edge.

**iPhone 5S**

Label and separator are 30 px (15pt) from the leading edge. All is good.

[image: iPhone 5S]

**iPhone 6 Plus**

Label is 48 px (15pt) from the leading edge and the separator is 60px (20pt) from the leading edge.

[image: iPhone 6 Plus]

If i log the tableView.separatorInset it's 15pt on the iPhone 5S and 20pt on the 6 Plus. Setting the inset to 15 on the 6 Plus manually doesn't work.

Please send help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, even after the recent iOS 8.1.1 update.   The weird thing is that this only happens on custom styled table view cells.

Comment: Tried this out on an iPad and it also happens.

Comment: Any solution found?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Override layoutMargins method in your custom cell class.

```
 - (UIEdgeInsets)layoutMargins
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: What's better way to do this without hard coding number?

Comment: A better way is to disable separator and add a custom view as separator.

Comment: For the proper way to do it, check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420888/uitableviewcell-with-autolayout-left-margin-different-on-iphone-and-ipad). The reason why that is the proper way is because it respects the larger left margin of a larger device like 6 Plus or iPad. Apple set the margin to be larger for a reason, so it looks better, and the apps should respect that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Storyboard, select the Table View attributes inspector. Change the

> Separator Inset

to

> Custom

and leave the default left margin as `15`.

Comment: For IOS 9, this solution worked for me. I was using a custom cell that contained a label with a 15pt constraint to the leading edge. The 15pt constraint worked great with all iPhones except with the iPhone 6+ & iPad (the label wasn't aligned with the tableview's separator inset). This solution fixed the problem though. Thanks!

Comment: Works also on iOS 8. Most easy solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but it worked for me.

```
@IBOutlet weak var leftViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    switch UIScreen.mainScreen().scale {
    case 2:
        leftViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 7.0
    case 3:
        leftViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 11.0
    default:
        assertionFailure("Error: wrong scale value")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer didn't get votes. It worked perfectly for me! I adjusted the leading edge constraint in the layoutSubviews method in my UITableViewCell subclass if the scale is 3, and in the Storyboard, I specified the  leading edge constraint to have a value of 12 (I think 11 is wrong) if the size class is Regular width x Any height.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by this solution:
http://qiita.com/mono0926/items/42f7a344b39e946abfe2

Get `tableView.separatorInset.left` value when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    notificationLabelLeft.constant = tableView.separatorInset.left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make this option of the table to false and it will work the same on all devices, especially on iPad.

```
cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```